# conda install tensorflow fails with Python version exception

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I’m stuck trying to install TensorFlow on a Windows 7 machine. Here’s what I’ve done so far:

```
> conda config --add channels conda-forge
> activate tensorflow
> conda install tensorflow
```

That caused this exception:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict: 
- python 3.6*
- tensorflow -> 
- python 3.5*
```

So I installed Python 3.5 then:

```
> deactivate py36
> activate py35
> conda install tensorflow
```

Same exception. I also tried running the install command from the Python35 directory without success.

**UPDATE**
I’m not going to answer my own question because someone might come along with a better answer. I’m a .NET guy and relatively new to Python. Here’s what I did:

1. Cleaned up my Python environment by deleting the various installs. Maybe not necessary to accomplish the objective but reduced the problem domain.
2. Installed the latest version of Anaconda. Note: this is a Python 3.6 implementation.
3. Created my TensorFlow environment: **> conda create --name tensorflow
   python=3.5**
4. Activated the new environment: **> activate tensorflow**
5. Checked to confirm: **> conda info –envs** The results of running this command should be a list of your environments with an asterisk in front of the tensorflow environment. **Important note:** Activating environments from PowerShell *didn’t work*. I had to do this in the command line window.
6. Per the instructions on the TensorFlow site, used the following command to install TensorFlow: **pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl**

According to the response to that last line the installation was a success:

*Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.3 numpy-1.12.1 packaging-16.8 protobuf-3.3.0
pyparsing-2.2.0 setuptools-35.0.2 six-1.10.0 tensorflow-1.1.0 werkzeug-0.12.2 wh
eel-0.29.0*

I haven't been able to get it to work in a Jupyter notebook but that's a topic for another SO thread.

Comment: I believe conda's default channel (Anaconda) only have binaries for linux (if you are trying to install tensorflow 1.0.0 at least) and other versions may be incompatible with python 3.5. Have you tried installing via `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`

Comment: Thanks. Looking at my installed programs in  Control Panel I see that the only Anaconda Python install is 3.6 so using conda to install TensorFlow won't work. Will try to use pip

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. It was in Windows 10 though.
Currently, Tensorflow only works with 64-bit windows, not 32-bit.
So, you could create a new 64-bit environment and install tensorflow in it:

```
set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=
conda create --name name_of_your_created_environment python=3.5
activate name_of_your_created_environment
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1 sets to a 32-bit environment whilst CONDA_FORCE_32BIT= sets to a 64-bit environment.

Answer (score 0):

When installing TFx on Windows, I suggest using the following versions:

- python=3.7
- tensorflow==2.3.0
- tfx==0.24.1

Feel free to have a look at this [blog](https://www.adaltas.com/en/2021/03/05/tfx-overview/)
It seems that the latest versions of Tensorflow and tfx are only compatible with Linux and macOS operating systems.